# Swap nodes (with pointers) on doubly circular linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I am trying to write a **doubly circular linked list**, but I got somewhat stuck in swapping nodes. It's working fine for any node except the head node. I tried adding a check if `node1` is the `head` without a luck. Where am I doing wrong ?

Well, I stated earlier but for any other node except head the swap is working just fine, I'm sure this is the key to the problem here, but I cannot see it so far. Appreciate any help.

`updateNode(*node)` simply rearrange prev->next and next->prev accordingly.

**Update:** Currently if `node1` is the head node, it swaps `node2` with `head->next`. `1 2 3 4 5 6` becomes `1 6 2 3 4 5`.

```cc
template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::updateNode(Node<T> *node) {
    node->prev->next = node;
    node->next->prev = node;
}


template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::swap(Node<T> *node1, Node<T> *node2) {
    if (!contains(node1) or !contains(node2)) 
        return;

    if (node1 == node2)
        return;
    else if (node2->next == node1 && node1->prev == node2) {
        Node<T> *temp = node1;
        node1 = node2;
        node2 = temp;
    }

    Node<T> *n1_prev = node1->prev;
    Node<T> *n2_prev = node2->prev;
    Node<T> *n1_next = node1->next;
    Node<T> *n2_next = node2->next;

    if (node1 == head && node2 == head->prev) {
        head->prev = node1;
        head = node2;
        head->next = n1_next;
        head->prev->prev = n2_prev;
    }
    else if (( node1->next == node2 && node2->prev == node1 ) || ( node1->prev == node2 && node2->next == node1 )) {
        node1->prev = n1_next;
        node2->prev = n1_prev;
        node1->next = n2_next;
        node2->next = n2_prev;
    }
    else {
        node1->prev = n2_prev;
        node2->prev = n1_prev;
        node1->next = n2_next;
        node2->next = n1_next;
    }

    updateNode(node1);
    updateNode(node2);
}
```

Comment: Depending on what is in the node, it may be easier to swap the contents and leave the nodes where they are.

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible example. can't run this code without at least the insert member function.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating this. Swap the nodes just like you normally would and when that's done, check if ether of the swapped nodes is the head. If yes, update the head to point at the other node.

Comment: i mean, it's weird that the Node class would be exposed like this at all. If the Node class is public why bother having a LinkedList class? the LinkedList class can't enforce a class invariant if the Nodes and be messed with willy-nilly.

Comment: @user4581301 yes, with swapping data its simpler indeed, but I don't see what's wrong here, as the question title suggests I need an implementation of swapping nodes without swapping data.

Comment: @jwezorek, Node class isn't exposed, but the nodes of the linked list can be accessed through a public method, sth like getNode(index), or firstNode() and lastNode(), so since they are public methods, the nodes are accessible.

Comment: @jwezorek in terms of reproducability you are correct, maybe I can post a minimal reproducible code snippet

Comment: Do you have scaffolding such as `void remove(Node<T> *node)` and `void insert(Node<T> *node, Node<T> *position)`? If you do, `pos1 = node1->prev; pos2 = node2->prev; remove(node1); remove(node2); insert(node1, pos2); insert(node2, pos1);` and done. `head` should have been handled by the `insert` and `remove` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the problems include:

- With `head->prev = node1` the node reference `node1` is made to refer to itself, as at that moment `head` and `node1` reference the same node.
- `head` should be changed also in other cases: it should change when it is equal to either `node1` or `node2` without any other condition. And then it should just reference the other of the two.
- The swap logic should not be any different when one of the nodes is the head node. The rewiring for the swap should be exactly the same. It is just (like mentioned above) that if one of them is the head, the `head` reference should be updated to refer to the other node of the two.
- In case the list consists only of two nodes (the ones to be swapped) then nothing needs to be rewired. Only the `head` reference should change.

Some conditions could be simplified, as we may assume that the list is consistent. So when `node2->next == node1` we may silently assume that `node1->prev == node2`, ...etc.

So here is an update of your code:

```
template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::swap(Node<T> *node1, Node<T> *node2) {
    if (!contains(node1) or !contains(node2)) 
        return;

    if (node1 == node2)
        return;
    
    if (node2->next == node1) {
        Node<T> *temp = node1;
        node1 = node2;
        node2 = temp;
    }

    if (node2->next != node1) { // More than 2 nodes in the list
        Node<T> *n1_prev = node1->prev;
        Node<T> *n2_next = node2->next;

        if (node1->next == node2) {
            node1->prev = node1->next;
            node2->next = node2->prev;
        } else {
            node1->prev = node2->prev;
            node2->next = node1->next;
        }
        node2->prev = n1_prev;
        node1->next = n2_next;

        updateNode(node1);
        updateNode(node2);
    }
    // If head was swapped, it should reference the other one now
    if (head == node1)
        head = node2;
    else if (head == node2)
        head = node1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification and refactor. I thought I could simply modify the head to point changed node in the if block `if (node1 == head && node2 == head->prev)`.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I understood the purpose of that `if` block, but it dealt only with one specific case. As I wrote in the second bullet point, there are several other cases where `head` needs to change, and the `if..else if` block I put at the end, deals with them all.